# Moving a object randomly without it being inside a wall - Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random, collider

i am trying to make some types of pickups spawn inside a given area, although some usually get stuck within the walls, how would i fix this?

Code in question for moving objects

```
for (int x = 0; x < garbage.Length; x++) 
{
    if (x < 5)
    {
        garbage[x].transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-33.0f, 30.0f), 2.35f, Random.Range(30.0f, -35.0f)); 
    }
}
```

Fixed it using Physics.OverlapSphere. Thanks.

Comment: why do they get stuck? are your walls spaced at least a bit further away than your random.range?

Comment: the walls including the playable area are included in the random range.

Comment: You'd probably want to do some collision checking on the pickup's scripts to check if they're within a wall, then try to push them out accordingly.

Comment: 2d/3d? Get the size of the elements and add/substract the half of it to the start/end of the range

Comment: The scenery itself is 3D.

Comment: You should do what @TJ Wolschon suggests.

Comment: @Ruben. See the chat under my question for info about how to get my answer working, or to discuss it.

Comment: Sure, how do we start a chat?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a while loop inside your if statement, so it would be like

```
int attempts = 0;
while(garbage[x].transform.position == /*[the range of coordinates for the wall]*/ || attempts = 0)
{
    garbage[x].transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-33.0f, 30.0f), 2.35f, Random.Range(30.0f, -35.0f));
    attempts += 1;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Using random number to control `while` loop is bound to cause your app to freeze. Maybe it's fine a coroutine function while yielding every frame but don't do it in a non coroutine function.

Comment: @Programmer assuming this is an initial render of the world then a short freeze shouldn't be a problem, if it were to be a problem then yes a co-routine would be suitable: i'll edit my answer.

Comment: While loops are notorious for causing crashes, not just short freezes. Even when everything looks like it should work. In Unity it is best to avoid them.

Comment: What's an alternative solution then?

Comment: Why don't you use colliders. If your pickup spawns inside a collider with tag wall, then delete it and try and respawn it again on the next update.

Comment: Is that not going to essentially be another while loop

Comment: Use update instead of while loops in Unity. Even if it has the same function. Or coroutine as stated by programmer.

Comment: you can check for collisions before spawning using Physics.OverlapSphere

Comment: How would i achieve this using a physics.OverlapSphere @zambari

Comment: You can check for collisons against a 'virtual' collider (which is what OverlapSphere does) without moving actual colliders, and without having to wait a frame for physics update. The method returns a list of colliders that overlap a virtual sphere with a center and radius you specify

Answer (score 0):

You can try `OnCollisionStay` to tackle this with collisions. `OnCollisionStay` can be very cpu heavy if not used carefully, so you may want to think of a better way if you can.

You will have to create a new script using the following code, which you will attach to your power-up prefab.

```
bool keepChecking = true;
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
{
    if(keepChecking)
    {
        if(collision.gameobject.tag == "Wall")
        {
            collision.gameobject.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-33.0f, 30.0f), 2.35f, Random.Range(30.0f, -35.0f));
        }
        else
        {
             keepChecking = false;
        }
     }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionStay.html

Read that link and make sure your objects have all the requirements. Your wall and Power-Up should have colliders, and at least one of these two should have a rigid body. None of these objects should be kinematic.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172264/discussion-on-answer-by-tyler-s-loeper-moving-a-object-randomly-without-it-bein).